# Unable to send file blobs to specific Salesforce Lightning folders for testing

Tags: apex, lightning, salesforce-id, folder

I recently developed a script that could integrate with Salesforce and move documents via file blobs to individual Salesforce folders but with our organizations recent migration to Salesforce Lightning, I'm not able to find the Folder IDs that are needed to point captured files towards. My current code snippet is as follows:

```
spo_file=test.txt
Document doc = new Document(Name=spo_file, Body=res.getBodyAsBlob(), FolderId=folder_id);
insert doc;
Blob headerValue= blob.valueOf(res.getBody());
String body = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
```

The problem I have here is that the original [Folder IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) for document folders are no longer appearing in the new Salesforce Lightning folders since they now use Case Safe IDs and I haven't been able to find a workaround that gives me Folder IDs that I can use in my Apex code. Any ideas on where I should begin?

Here is a below error message I sometimes get from Apex due to the Case Safe Folder ID:

[image: Salesforce Apex periodic code failure]

Comment: Do you have a custom folder Object? a0q is a custom object id

Comment: No. When I created the Document Folder for a TestFolder, this is what it gave me as the 'Document Folder Id CASESAFE' value

Comment: DOcument Folder starts with `00l`,

Comment: How do I get that in Lightning?

Comment: Create custom UI, and use this SOQL to get all document folders, 
`SELECT Id,CreatedDate,DeveloperName,Type FROM Folder WHERE TYpe ='Document'`

Comment: So that query isn't going to work if it requires my Apex script to correctly run. What do you mean when you say "create custom UI"?

Comment: I tried modifying the following: `Document doc = new Document(Name=spo_file, Body=res.getBodyAsBlob(), FolderId=[SELECT Id FROM Folder WHERE name ='TestFolder'].id);` but I got back this error message: **System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject**. The folder name is valid in my Salesforce instance.